# How can I make this figure?

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw this figure in ShareLaTeX ?

[image]

Here is MWE :

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{Project,
net present value , Risk , Green gas effect , payback period , benefitcost analysis , Rate of return }
\end{document}
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: You can start from here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/smart-constellation/

Comment: How can I inverse the direction of the arrows and the color of the circles ?

Comment: I have not seen into the code :-( sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the direction of the arrows with

```
/tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-}
```

The code would look like this

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{
  planet size=2.5cm, 
  satellite size=2.5cm, 
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-}
} 

\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{Project,
net present value , Risk , Green gas effect , payback period , benefitcost analysis , Rate of return }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderfull, and how can I change the color of the circles ?

Comment: And also I want to have the same color for all the arrows, same color of the circles.

Comment: You can add them with

    `set color list={color1, color2, color3, ...}`

as for the arrows

    `uniform connection color=true`

Comment: i check `smartdiagram` documentation and didn't find anything about possibilities to add `tikz` styles :-(. learning from your answer (+1) for my experiment i try tte following: `\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\smartdiagramset{
  planet size=2cm,
  satellite size=2.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={{Triangle[length=3mm,width=6mm]}-,line width=4mm},
}`. result is intriguing :-)

Comment: @Zarko intriguing indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

I will do it using tikz package, you can easily control the size of your circles.

You can start from a simpler example like:

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/